# 301 all 404s to homepage

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Apache, tomcat, linux

Comment: I HATE HATE HATE it when I get one letter wrong in a URL, and it redirects me to the home page and changes the URL I typed to the home page one.  If I make a mistake, let me fix it, dammit!

Comment: Alan, I assume some people already hate you just for asking. And they have a point.

Comment: Don't ! EOD. For the same point Tomblin already made. I don't hate you for asking, but still - don't.

Comment: I hate it too. But did you stop to think why i wanted to do this instead of just assuming im an idiot?

Its a small personal site, not a money maker. Rebuilt it to learn a new technology. Not bothered 301ing pages to their new versions. So instead trying to get some value to the homepage.

Comment: but just for you guys, ill go and make a nice 404 page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also the tomcat way: stick in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/homepage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Relative to web apps context.

Answer (score 3):

Don't, unless is really a permantent move. Otherwise, return 404.

Telling anyone your 404 page is 301, means it would show the actual content related to the URL that was asked for. Important for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

404s should be 404s. Design a good and usable 404 page with appropriate message, link back to homepage, search form and auto discovered possible related pages.

The Smashing Magazine has a [very good article on designing 404 pages](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/25/wanted-your-404-error-pages/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

Absolute URLs are being redirected.